# .NET console app showing certain Unicode value as question mark; is this fixable?

Tags: .net, unicode, console-application

I am writing a .NET 5 console application in C#.  One of the things I would like to be able to do is to display two specific Unicode characters: a full heart (`♥` - Unicode number 2665) and an empty heart (`♡` - Unicode number 2661).  Thus:

```
const char emptyHeart = '\u2661';
const char fullHeart = '\u2665';
```

I assume I have that set properly, but for some reason the console is showing the `emptyHeart` as a question mark instead of the proper character.  Thus, for example, a string containing three `fullHeart`s followed by four `emptyHeart`s shows as `♥♥♥????` instead of the intended `♥♥♥♡♡♡♡`.  Is this fixable without changing the Unicode characters (such as to filled and empty circles)?  If so, how?

Comment: I found another similar question on SO that may be relevant to your issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9100267/1188197.  Yours is C# not Java, but may still lead you towards a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: Yes, I looked at both of those, and no, it doesn't answer my question.  Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=net-5.0#notes-to-callers

> Note that successfully displaying Unicode characters to the console requires the following:
>
> - The console must use a TrueType font, such as Lucida Console or Consolas, to display characters.
> - **A font used by the console must define the particular glyph or glyphs to be displayed.** The console can take advantage of font linking to display glyphs from linked fonts if the base font does not contain a definition for that glyph.

The default Windows console font, Consolas, does include a glyph for \u2665, but not for \u2661 as per the U+2660 row from https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/consolas/grid.htm.

Your only option, therefore, is to change the console's font to one that does support that glyph. However this is not a trivial operation; see "The following example shows how you can programmatically change the font from a raster font to Lucida Console" from https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console#unicode-support-for-the-console (although Lucida Console doesn't support \u2661 either, so you'll have to find a font that does).

Comment: Thank you.  This is not exactly what I was hoping to hear, but it does answer my question.