# Display Unicode to the Console

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

I am creating a chess application and want to display my pieces with nice Unicode pieces. However, when I try to output the Unicode symbols I just get boxes with questionmarks in them for all my pieces.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    private Board boardInstance;
    Dictionary<int, string> pieceMappings = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 1, "\u2659" }, // White Pawn
        { 2, "\u2658" }, // White Knight
        { 3, "\u2657" }, // White Bishop
        { 4, "\u2656" }, // White Rook
        { 5, "\u2655" }, // White Queen
        { 6, "\u2654" }, // White King
        { 7, "\u265F" }, // Black Pawn
        { 8, "\u265E" }, // Black Knight
        { 9, "\u265D" }, // Black Bishop
        { 10, "\u265C" }, // Black Rook
        { 11, "\u265B" }, // Black Queen
        { 12, "\u265A" }  // Black King
    };

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        // Create an instance of the Program class 
        Program program = new();
        program.StartNewGame();
    }

    private void StartNewGame()
    {
        boardInstance = new();
        boardInstance.InitBoard();

        DrawBoard();
    }

    private void DrawBoard()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("   " + (8-i) + "    ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if (boardInstance.board[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(pieceMappings[boardInstance.board[i][j]] + "  ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("-  ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n        a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h\n");
    }
```

What I tried:

- Change font, I use Consolas which I heard should work. This is the main fix I saw across previous responses but did nothing for me.
- Added the line "Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8" which you see in the code but did nothing.

How can I display the pieces in the console?

Comment: Like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/FCpGO2? It depends on the font that your terminal uses.

Comment: Strings in .NET are Unicode. Just print the characters `foreach(var p in pieceMappings.Values){ Console.WriteLine(p); }`. These will print just fine in Windows Terminal

Comment: There's no need for `Convert.ToChar(pieceMappings[...]` to convert the string. .NET strings are already Unicode. The contents of the dictionary already are the actual Unicode characters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry that was something I tried that dodn't work either. Missed to remove it here

Comment: @eligolf it works just fine. The very first comment links to an online example that just works. I tried this code in Windows Terminal just now and it works. How did you try to run your program?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. I need to use like pieceMappings[5].Value but it says "string does not contain a definition for Value

Comment: `pieceMappings[5]` gives you a string, not a `KeyValuePair`. You don't need to `.Value` it.

Comment: @gunr2171, then I don't see any difference from my code. How can I fix it? It shows just questionmarks.

Comment: FWIW, I only get question marks when I run the code in my first comment on my computer.

Comment: There's nothing to fix. There are no question marks when we run the code. How did *you* run the code? Did you run it in *Windows Terminal* or the old Console? On what OS? In Windows 11 and Windows 10 versions in the last 5 years or so both Windows Terminal and the old Console will display the chess pieces

Comment: @gunr2171, then no closer to a solution I guess, I only care for what is run on my computer since it is a private project :(

Comment: We don't know what's on your computer, how it's configured or what's wrong on that single machine. On older Windows versions you had to change the codepage to UTF7 with `chcp 65001`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, gunr didn't manage on his computer either apparently, just on the webpage. I run it in Visual Studio 2019 and whatever console comes up when I run it through that.

Comment: Yes, because that webpage uses NET Core, not .NET Framework. What did you use, .NET Framework or .NET Core? What OS version? You have to include enough information so others can reproduce the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, .Net Core on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _I'm_ using W10, .Net 7. Win Terminal using consolas, Cascadia Code, and Fira Code. PowerShell (admin) host using consolas. Even `Console.WriteLine("♙♘♗♖♕♔♟♞♝♜♛♚");`, which shows up correctly in the VS IDE using Fira Code, shows question marks in console (even with the same font selected).

Comment: I really think this is a font problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68737349/1043380

Comment: actually it depend on where you rander the output and if it suport unicode randering or not in .... vs 22 terminal win 11 [it work out of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bWd5.png) without any changing!

Comment: Ah, well as soon as I add `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`  before the foreach from Ibram's screenshot it shows the symbols correctly in Win Terminal (consolas, Fira Code, Cascadia Code). Different question mark in PS.

Comment: I think you need to follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0#unicode-support-for-the-console)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it also required a bit of work, but I finally got it working.

I followed [article I already mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0#unicode-support-for-the-console), and adjusted it a little, below is full code snippet.

Key to the problem for me was also finding correct font - I searched for a bit for font containing character you want and found Arial Unicode MS - I found [this site](https://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fontsbyrange.html), to look for the font and eventually found it [here](https://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols.html)

I installed the font on my OS and used it in console resulting in correct printing of the character `\u2659`:

[image]

Code sample (you need to enable `unsafe` code in your project):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal unsafe struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
    {
        internal uint cbSize;
        internal uint nFont;
        internal COORD dwFontSize;
        internal int FontFamily;
        internal int FontWeight;
        internal fixed char FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct COORD
    {
        internal short X;
        internal short Y;

        internal COORD(short x, short y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    private const int TMPF_TRUETYPE = 4;
    private const int LF_FACESIZE = 32;
    private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(
        IntPtr consoleOutput,
        bool maximumWindow,
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX consoleCurrentFontEx);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int dwType);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int SetConsoleFont(
        IntPtr hOut,
        uint dwFontNum);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SetConsoleFont("Arial Unicode MS");
        
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("\u2659");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void SetConsoleFont(string fontName = "Lucida Console")
    {
        unsafe
        {
            IntPtr hnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            if (hnd != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX info = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);
                CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX newInfo = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX();
                newInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(newInfo);
                newInfo.FontFamily = TMPF_TRUETYPE;
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(newInfo.FaceName);
                Marshal.Copy(fontName.ToCharArray(), 0, ptr, fontName.Length);
                // Get some settings from current font.
                newInfo.dwFontSize = new COORD(info.dwFontSize.X, info.dwFontSize.Y);
                newInfo.FontWeight = info.FontWeight;
                SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hnd, false, newInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```